# Use a table to update fields in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I'd like to implement the following functionality in my MS Word reports. Not sure how/if this is possible.

This is the image I have in mind, for reference:

[image: example of what I want]

1. At the beginning of a report, include a table of inputs containing all the parameters.
2. Throughout the content of the report, setup fields that will change when the inputs in the Table change.
3. Example: PARAMETER 1 is set to 100, all PARAMETER 1s in the Content section will then automatically change to 100.

Thank you

Comment: Does it have to be a table in the document itself? If not, you could do [a regular mail merge](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/mail-merge-using-an-excel-spreadsheet-858c7d7f-5cc0-4ba1-9a7b-0a948fa3d7d3), but with 1 row in the accompanying Excel sheet.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke I did not know about a mail merge, I do think that could work. Will try it out and let you know/update the post. Thanks!

Comment: I've added an answer that is very close to what you were looking for.

Comment: There are several possibilities, but have you looked at using "legacy form fields" and "protected forms" to allow entry of the the data, and { REF } fields to display the results?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to implement this requirement with VBA.

Open VBA console: Click "Alt + F11"

Here's the macro generated by the screen recording, which you can refer to:

```
Sub Macro5()
Selection.TypeText Text:="100"
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
        .Text = "parameter1"
        .Replacement.Text = "100"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindAsk
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    Selection.TypeText Text:="200"
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "parameter2"
        .Replacement.Text = "200"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindAsk
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    Selection.TypeText Text:="300"
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "parameter3"
        .Replacement.Text = "300"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindAsk
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

You only need to modify the following two parameters to control the value of the variable:

TypeText Text:="XX"   Replacement.Text = "XX"

Comment: This would replace all occurrences of `PARAMETER1` and `PARAMETER2` right? Regardless if this is a placeholder or just regular text. So if there would be a sentence that said: "PARAMETER1 is equal to `PARAMETER1`" the macro you propose would convert it to : "100 is equal to `100`", instead of "PARAMETER1 is equal to `100`", right?

Comment: This would replace all occurrences of PARAMETER1 and PARAMETER2. Assign a value to a parameter and then perform a replace.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a way which is pretty close to what you want, however instead of a table in the document you have to use the Advanced Properties of a document.

These are the steps from scratch (for a recent version of Word on Windows):

1. Create a new document
2. Go to File ➡ Properties (upper right) ➡ Advanced Properties:

[image]

3. Then go to the Custom tab in the window that appears
4. Here you can create custom document properties, which you can use to store the parameter values as below GIF shows (sorry for the typo):

[image]

5. Now go back to the document. There you can use [fieldcodes](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/list-of-field-codes-in-word-1ad6d91a-55a7-4a8d-b535-cf7888659a51) to show document properties.
6. Easiest is to go to the location where you want the parameter text to appear, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>, type `DOCPROPERTY  parameter_name  \* MERGEFORMAT` and then press <kbd>F9</kbd> to update all fieldcodes in the document (including the one you just created):

[image]

7. Repeat it at every location you want the parameter(s) to appear

To change the parameter value across the document, update it in the Advanced Properties (step 2-3), go back to the document and update all fieldcodes by pressing <kbd>F9</kbd>.

Here's a short demo:

[image]